# Create table with SELECT syntax in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, create-table

I would like to know how MySQL interprets the `CREATE TABLE` syntax:

If I write:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
    `v1` int,
    `v2` int
     CONSTRAINT idx PRIMARY KEY (v1)
)
SELECT a, b FROM tbl2;
```

- Does it determine which value goes into `v1` and which goes into `v2`
  by their order in the select statement?
- Does it use the names I designate in the `CREATE TABLE` statement or
  does it take them from the select statement?

I have used the `CREATE TABLE XX SELECT val FROM YY` before but would like to know more specifically about the above syntax.

Comment: I sugest that you use PhpMyAdmin. It is much easier!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With your current solution you'll get a table with the columns `v1`, `v2`, `a`, and `b`.

To see how it is done properly, see the ["CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Statement"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html) chapter in the official MySQL documentation.

So if you just want `v1` and `v2` with an *index* on `v1`, do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (PRIMARY KEY (v1))
SELECT a v1,
       b v2
FROM tbl2;
```